# Save Javascript or Replace Javascript File in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to replace a .js file in the website sources with a file on my workstation, or make a modification to a .js file and refresh the website to see the changes?

I am developing client-side JavaScript code against a SharePoint website on a server. I cannot create a local version of the website, so I need to modify the script, save the file to the server, refresh, etc. I do not have direct access to the server, and saving a file in a SP doc library or web part takes a lot of time between edits.

I can make small modifications using the dev tools while breaking on certain lines and applying snippets, but I am hoping for a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access the server that's hosting the file you should be able to replace or modify the JS file. Alternately you can use local hosting tools to test your file and then upload it to the server once you've confirmed it's working.
If you explain what you level of access to your host is we can offer better suggestions.

Comment: I do not have direct access to the server. Question edited for clarity